# Horizontal listview not scrolling on web but scrolling on mobile

Tags: flutter, listview, web, scroll

After flutter 2.5 update listview is scrolling only on mobile platforms. It doesn't scroll when I open it on the web. It was working fine in the previous version. I tried the scroll physics but it didn't work.  what do you suggest i do? sorry for my bad english.

```
          return SizedBox(
            height: 400,
            child: ListView.builder(
                physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                // ignore: unnecessary_null_comparison
                itemCount: items == null ? 0 : items.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        LoginForm();
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        margin:
                            EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 6),
                        child: SizedBox(
                          width: 400,
                          height: 50,
                          child: Stack(
                            fit: StackFit.expand,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    borderRadius:
                                        BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),
                                    boxShadow: [
                                      BoxShadow(
                                          color: fromCssColor(
                                              items[index].color.toString()),
                                          // color: Colors.black38,
                                          offset: Offset(2.0, 2.0),
                                          blurRadius: 5.0,
                                          spreadRadius: 1.0)
                                    ]),
                              ),
                              ClipRRect(
                                borderRadius:
                                    BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),
                                child: Image.asset(
                                  items[index].image.toString(),
                                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                ),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    borderRadius:
                                        BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),
                                    gradient: LinearGradient(
                                        begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                                        end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                                        colors: [
                                          Colors.transparent,
                                          Colors.black45
                                        ]))
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
```

Comment: try: `MaterialApp(
scrollBehavior: MaterialScrollBehavior().copyWith(
dragDevices: {PointerDeviceKind.mouse},
), ...`

Comment: Thanks. and can use ScrollConfiguration.of(context).copyWith(...) too

Answer (score 120, accepted):

### Flutter 2.5 Summary

> `ScrollBehaviors` now allow or disallow drag scrolling from specified
> `PointerDeviceKinds`. `ScrollBehavior.dragDevices`, by default, allows
> scrolling widgets to be dragged by all `PointerDeviceKinds` except for
> `PointerDeviceKind.mouse`.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

// Set ScrollBehavior for an entire application.
MaterialApp(
  scrollBehavior: MyCustomScrollBehavior(),
  // ...
);
```

```dart
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyCustomScrollBehavior extends MaterialScrollBehavior {
  // Override behavior methods and getters like dragDevices
  @override
  Set<PointerDeviceKind> get dragDevices => {
        PointerDeviceKind.touch,
        PointerDeviceKind.mouse,
      };
}
```

[Reference to the official documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/default-scroll-behavior-drag).

Comment: Is this supposed to be included exactly as you've written it here? I get "undefined name PointerDeviceKind". I also notice that the Flutter documentation page for PointerDeviceKind, which is linked at the bottom of the page you linked to, is a 404.  https://master-api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/PointerDeviceKind-class.html

Comment: I am amazed.  Thanks this worked.  Chrome was not allowing horizontal scrolling for listview.

Comment: Link for more information https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/default-scroll-behavior-drag

Comment: It does work, I dont know why flutter doesnt make this default

Answer (score 6):

If you want solution for specific Widget Try below

```dart
    class MyCustomScrollBehavior extends MaterialScrollBehavior {
      // Override behavior methods and getters like dragDevices
      @override
      Set<PointerDeviceKind> get dragDevices => { 
        PointerDeviceKind.touch,
        PointerDeviceKind.mouse,
        // etc.
      };
    }
    
    // ScrollBehavior can be set for a specific widget.
    final ScrollController controller = ScrollController();
    ScrollConfiguration(
      behavior: MyCustomScrollBehavior(),
      child: ListView.builder(
        controller: controller,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
         return Text('Item $index');
        }
      ),
    );
```

more information [flutter dev](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/default-scroll-behavior-drag#setting-a-custom-scrollbehavior-for-a-specific-widget)

Comment: Also works with normal ListView widgets (ie: doesn't have to be ListView.builder)

Comment: @SpiRail of course

Answer (score 4):

**I was able to solve this issue by putting following code in my MaterialApp widget**

```
  scrollBehavior: const MaterialScrollBehavior().copyWith(
    dragDevices: {PointerDeviceKind.mouse},
  ),
```

**My code**

```
return MaterialApp(
  scrollBehavior: const MaterialScrollBehavior().copyWith(
    dragDevices: {PointerDeviceKind.mouse},
  ),
  title: 'Flutter app',
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  theme: ThemeData(useMaterial3: true),
  home: const SplashScreen(),
);
```

Comment: does this break mobile though?

Comment: @Tom This way would break mobile but the following code will ensure both work: 

  scrollBehavior: ScrollConfiguration.of(context).copyWith(
    dragDevices: {
      PointerDeviceKind.touch,
      PointerDeviceKind.mouse,
    },