# ListView widget not entirely visible when scaled

Tags: flutter, dart

When I scale a horizontal `ListView` widget, I observe that only a portion of the list items are visible when the widget is scrolled all the way to the right:

```
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final sideLength = 50.0;
    final scale = 2.0;

    return MaterialApp(
        scrollBehavior: MyCustomScrollBehavior(),
        home: Scaffold(
            body: Transform.scale(
          scale: scale,
          alignment: Alignment(-1, -1),
          child: Container(
              height: sideLength * scale,
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: 20,
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
                    width: sideLength,
                    height: sideLength,
                    child: Text(index.toString()),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(width: 3, color: Colors.red))),
              )),
        )));
  }
}

class MyCustomScrollBehavior extends MaterialScrollBehavior {
  // Override behavior methods and getters like dragDevices
  @override
  Set<PointerDeviceKind> get dragDevices => {
        PointerDeviceKind.touch,
        PointerDeviceKind.mouse,
      };
}
```

On the Pixel 2 emulator, only the first 16 items are visible when I scroll to extreme right. For example:

[image]

When  the scale is 1 or if the `Transform.scale` widget is not there, all 20 items are visible.

I observe the following behavior:

| Total item count | Last item scrollable to |
| --- | --- |
| 8 | 4 |
| 10 | 6 |
| 20 | 16 |
| 30 | 26 |
| 50 | 46 |

So it seems like the last 4 items are always left out.

Ultimately my goal is to create a responsive widget that scales according to the dimensions of screen, so I'm looking for a generic solution.

The custom scroll behavior is only there so that horizontal scrolling works on dartpad.dev, as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69154468/horizontal-listview-not-scrolling-on-web-but-scrolling-on-mobile).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked around this issue by:

- setting `itemCount` to a higher value than the desired item count. This allows you to scroll to the last desired item in the `ListView`
- having a scroll controller that checks whether you're past the last visible desired item within the viewport. If so, jump to the last possible scroll offset within the viewport

```
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
  static const actualTotalItems = 20;
  static const sideLength = 50.0;
  static const scale = 2.0;

  MyApp() {
    _scrollController.addListener(() {
      if (_scrollController.offset > sideLength * actualTotalItems - _scrollController.position.viewportDimension / scale) {
        _scrollController.jumpTo(sideLength * actualTotalItems - _scrollController.position.viewportDimension / scale);
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        scrollBehavior: MyCustomScrollBehavior(),
        home: Scaffold(
            body: Container(
                transform: Matrix4.diagonal3Values(scale, scale, 1),
                height: sideLength * scale,
                child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: actualTotalItems * 2,
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    controller: _scrollController,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
                        width: sideLength,
                        height: sideLength,
                        child: Text(index.toString()),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(width: 3, color: Colors.red)))))));
  }
}

class MyCustomScrollBehavior extends MaterialScrollBehavior {
  // Override behavior methods and getters like dragDevices
  @override
  Set<PointerDeviceKind> get dragDevices => {
        PointerDeviceKind.touch,
        PointerDeviceKind.mouse,
      };
}
```

I scaled the widget using the `transform` property in the `Container` to have a smaller widget tree, but that has no impact on the solution. The Transform widget could have been used as in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

**Transform** only affects how the child should be painted.

On the other hand, The **scale** argument multiplies the x and y axes.

**For example**: Imagine a photographer who is taking a landscape photo that contains a tree, now if the photographer gets closer to the tree, the upper part of the tree will slightly be out of the photo.

Try adding **padding** or **margin** to the **Container** and observe how the widget is affected by the **scale**.
Then you will know how to manipulate it.

```
body: Transform.scale(
              scale: scale,
              alignment: Alignment(0, -5),
              child: Container(
                  height: sideLength * scale,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 100, right: 100),
                  child: ListView.builder(
```

Comment: This requires a lot of guess work. Furthermore, setting the alignment of the transformation and the margin changes where and how the Container is rendered.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant when I said you will know how to manipulate it.

Comment: I don't think I can change the alignment and margin. I want my widget to be displayed in a certain way at a particular location, and this solution does not do that. Setting the margin could result in the widget being displayed in the middle of the screen. Ultimately I want to scale a widget and for it behave as any other widget and for the subsequent widgets to respect the scaled dimensions.

Comment: The guesswork can be handled with simple math equations.

Comment: Can you please specify the desired output? I am interested in your topic.

Comment: The output should be exactly what is what displayed when you run the program on an emulator or dartpad.dev except that it should be possible to scroll all the way to the 20th list element. I've updated the OP for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Give here width and height by **MediaQuery**

Widget build(BuildContext context) {

```
return MaterialApp(
    scrollBehavior: MyCustomScrollBehavior(),
    home: Scaffold(
        body: Transform.scale(
      scale: scale,
      alignment: Alignment(-1, -1),
      child: Container(
          height: sideLength * scale,
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: 20,
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.90 ,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.80 ,
                child: Text(index.toString()),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(width: 3, color: Colors.red))),
          )),
    )));
```

}

Comment: This makes every list item almost equal to the width of the screen. I don't want to change the dimensions of the inner most Container. Furthermore, the last element in the list is only partially shown. This happens regardless of the number of items.